# Crosswalk,how to change textsize?

Tags: android, crosswalk

I want to change `textsize` of `XWalkView`,but I can't use these method
`getSettings()`  and `setTextZoom()`. so, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link, this might be helpful for you:

> https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-test-suite/blob/master/usecase/usecase-embedding-android-tests/embeddingapi/src/org/xwalk/embedded/api/sample/setting/XWalkViewSettingTextZoom.java